# Panda column value change based on another column by lamda function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a panda dataframe:

```
star = pd.DataFrame({'Country':['Canada','USA', 'Mexico'],'Rating':[1,2,3], 'Score':[70,80,90]})
```

I want to give Rating value 3 to Canada. And this code works.

```
star.loc[star['Country'] == 'Canada', 'Rating'] = 3
```

But I want to do it with lambda function:

```
star.Rating.map(lambda x: 3 if star.Country == 'Canada')
```

Gives a syntax error

```
File "<ipython-input-41-544a311d7f86>", line 1
    star.Rating.map(lambda x: 3 if star.Country == 'Canada')
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want help in the lambda function

Comment: the question here is why you want to use a `lambda` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is indeed a syntax error. You should do:

```
star.apply(lambda x: 3 if x.Country == 'Canada' else x.Rating, axis=1)
```

However, your original solution is **much better**.

Comment: @Ben.T Thanks for the comment. One should use `apply` instead of `map`. And it should be applied on the data frame.

Comment: I second that the original solution is better and **faster**.

Comment: But my question is how to make the ```map``` work? What is the syntax error?

Comment: @user3141181 python syntax for ternary operation is `on_true if condition else on_false`. You missed `else` part. In addition `star.Country == 'Canada'` is a series, and you **cannot** put a series after `if`, i.e., you cannot convert a series to a boolen `True` or `False`. This issue with `if some_series` prevents you to use `map` on the series.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to avoid `apply` (or `map`) for these kind of problems. `np.where` is faster and easier to implement

```
star["Rating"] = np.where(star.Country=="Canada", 3, star.Rating)
```